# How is software opened through the GNOME terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gnome-terminal

I can't find where to open up software through the terminal. I remember opening Android Studio through the terminal but A.S. had directories listed. The last few times I installed (monodevelop, sublime text) I've not been able to find the installations in my directories. Is there another way to open software from the terminal?

Comment: Your previous commands will be stored in your `history` so you can view that for refreshers.  If I forget the name of a command (or more commonly am just lazy) I use <TAB> to autocomplete (<TAB><TAB> if it's not obvious and I want to see my options), and `whereis` to find where a program is located (it must be located with the $PATH). Programs are located using that $PATH (a list of directories that are searched for commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have execute the specific command to start specific softwore. Such as, if you want to start your File Manager, execute `nautilus`, to start Text Editor execute `gedit`. If you don't know the command, go to `/usr/share/applications/` using your File Manager and search  icon of the application you want to start. Right click the icon and select 'Open with other application'. Now open the file with Text Editor (or any of your choice) and search the `Exec=` line. The content after `Exec=` is the command to start the application. You can also start that application as root by using sudo if you have permission to use sudo.